# How to detect if current page is running in webview (not in external browser/system browser) with Dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, facebook-browser

I shared my web-app link on a Facebook post, my users click on this link and the page opens in Facebook webview. I want to alert them "You are viewing this page in Facebook browser, please open Chrome/Safari to run this web app".

How can I do this with Flutter?

I have searched many questions and answers but they just check if the page runs in Web, not in Webview!

Answer (score 1):

```
     if(html.window.navigator.userAgent.contains("FBAV") ||
                              html.window.navigator.userAgent
                                  .contains("Instagram")) {
await showDialog<void>(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text('Open in External Browser'),
                            content: 
                                const Text(
                                    'For the best experience, we recommend opening the website in your default browser.'),
                               
                              ],
                            ),
                            actions: [
                              TextButton(
                                child: const Text('Ok'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
}
```

### donot forget to add `import 'dart:html' as html;`
and have a nice day ❤️

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

    if (kIsWeb && (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android)) {
          /// you open your alert dialog to tell the user what you want
    }
```

this works because if link of your webapp is opened in the facebook app, it will be on a mobile device, if the user is using facebook web, it won't be using a webview.

Comment: Can you tell me which package to import?

Comment: It's not working because in Facebook webview, it's still the web, not Android or iOS

Comment: @JasonSG I edited my answer, the current check now tells you if your `webapp` has been opened on a web page (either webview or browser) but while on a mobile device